# supervisord: how to use environment variables in subprocess command?

Tags: supervisord

I want to use an environment variable in the subprocess command, eg:

```
[program:server]
command=/server/bin/server --loglevel=$LOGLEVEL
```

I also tried `%(ENV_LOGLEVEL)` which didn't work.

what is the proper way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe %(ENV_LOGLEVEL)s would be the correct way, but bear in mind that this was only added in version 3.0a11 - versions installed by eg apt-get on ubuntu may be older than this.